# Use Electron with USB

Tags: usb, electron

I'm currently searching for solutions to use USB within the Electron project.

I found many threads not just here on stack overflow. But all are stating different things. Some say it's working well (easily), others say it's not even possible.

I stumbled over usb-electron but this is only working in Electron prebuild 1.0.2 (as far as I know).

Is someone using Electron and USB in one project successfully? For what devices do you use this combination? Maybe someone is using another solution? Like a C# (or whatever) binary in the background that get's triggered within electron and doing all the USB stuff?

I'm thankful for every hint!

Update:

I tried those mentioned solutions and got various errors. I also never managed to build the USB or serialport packages against electron. If I use the serialport package I get the following error with electron 1.4.12:

```
angular.js:14328 Error: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.
\\?\E:\Masterthesis\Simplex-Electron\node_modules\serialport\build\Release\serialport.node
    at Error (native)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:583:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (E:\Masterthesis\Simplex-Electron\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
```

The first line just says that a DLL routine is failing.

Comment: Have you tried any of the available solutions yet? `node-serialport` it's a fantastic package that you can use to communicate over a serial bus and i confirm, it's working very well with Electron.

Comment: apparently you are on windows, this is not good for USB developing. when trying to build the `node-serialport` against electron did you follow the special instructions on https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport#electron ? `node-usb` uses `libusb` which has its own driver in windows, see https://github.com/tessel/node-usb. maybe this is a problem. it would be better to switch to linux for this ...

Comment: npm `electron-usb` https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-usb

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. I figured out that the hardware I tried to connect with (LEGO Mindstorms Education EV3) is a *HIDClass* device. Therefore it doesn't exposed itself as a COM interface. Libraries like `node-serialport` can't work with it.

I managed to compile `node-serialport` for Electron. That's working fine (if the USB device exposes itself as a COM device).

Others connection methods like WIFI (`node-net`) and Bluetooth (`node-bluetooth`) are working fine, too.

Maybe this information helps other.

Comment: HI, I have to make a desktop application which needs to communicate with a HW board over USB.  can we use React + Electron for this purpose? if any sample code you can share, that will be really helpful